# Global using of C# does not work in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some common class libraries widely used in my C# and `.cshtml` files.

After knowing the "global using" syntax I tried and always failed.
Then I realized that it does not work in my `.cshtml` file.

I've tried these methods:

1. Put it in a file named `GlobalUsing.cs` in the root folder where the `Program.cs` is.

   ```
    // Global using directives
    global using MfcUtilities;
   ```
2. Put it at the top of `Program.cs`:

   ```
    // Global using directives

    global using MfcUtilities;   // Before all the other usings.
    using AdaSpec.Controllers;
   ```
3. Put it at the top of the `.cshtml` (both the view using it, and `_ImportView.cshtml`). It did not work and an error "cannot resolve symbol 'global'" was raised.

   ```
    @global using MfcUtilities
    @using AdaSpec
   ```
4. And in the `.csproj` file:

   ```
        <ItemGroup>
            <Using Include="MfcUtilities" />
        </ItemGroup>
   ```

Then I realized that all the examples I've found are all about `.cs` files. So does it work for `.cshtml` files and how?

Thanks

Comment: "an error was rissed" - when you refer to an error in a question, it's *always* important to say what that error is.

Comment: Can you not use _Imports.cshtml or _ViewImports.cshtml to achieve the same sort of thing though?

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the error in my question. It's "cannot resolve symbol 'global'". Thanks.

Comment: Okay, that's better. I still don't see the point though - surely _Imports.cshtml or _ViewImports.cshtml has the same purpose as `global using` doesn't it? It allows you to specify your using directives in one place (for all Razor pages).

Comment: @JonSkeet _ViewImport.cshtml is the right place. Removing the "global" gets things done. See the answer bellow. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this difference in the execution of the command is related to the fact that CHTML files are executed by the RAZOR, in other words, this RAZOR is designed in such a way that its input files must be such that it can execute it.
In other words, the RAZOR is a library that is designed with a condition, and its designers need enough time to improve its performance with the latest features added to the relevant language.
In summary, in my opinion, this is not a special problem and we can use the previous solutions and wait until the next versions of the RAZOR to synchronize itself with the latest language attitude.

This feature is available in .NET 6 / C# 10 and after.
please check folowing urls:

> https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/19/global-using-statements-in-c10/
> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/global-using-directive-in-c-sharp-102/

You can create a file with name "_ViewImports.cshtml" in the root views directory.
now write all your global namespace at on:

```
@using MyNameSpaceName;
```

Comment: Ah! Great! So the _ViewImport.cshtml(I already have it) works as the "global" and all I need is "@using namespace"! Thanks!